# How to prepare env file for symfony app in docker?

Tags: symfony, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a `symfony` application i dockerized environment. To do so, I'd like `docker-compose` to fetch all the variables like db credentials or `APP_SECRET` from docker `.env` file and apply those values to some predefined `.env.dist`. So I have something like that in my `Dockerfile` for PHP container:

```
COPY ./app/.env.dist /var/www/app/.env
RUN sed -i 's/__APP_ENV__/'${APP_ENV}'/g' /var/www/app/.env
RUN sed -i 's/__APP_SECRET__/'${APP_SECRET}'/g' /var/www/app/.env
...
```

However, the problem is that these instructions are obviously executed before the volume is mounted so after the container is built and up the `.env` file I prepare with those commands is missing because the directory gets replaced with the mounted one. Is there a way to handle such situation in a nice way?

Basically, anything that could prepare an env file before build would be ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using this for development, I would recommend not mounting the entire volume with the source code, but instead add the source code to `/var/www/app` during the build process. That way when the container runs, you'll just need to run the entrypoint defined for that container.

Alternatively, you can prepare the `.env` file in a different directory, say `/var/www`, and define a custom command in your entrypoint script (which gets run after the mount) to copy the `.env` file in `/var/www` to `/var/www/app/.env`. Note that this will actually replace the `.env` file in the mounted volume, if one actually exists.

Comment: But will I be able to modify the files on my host IDE this way?

Comment: Yes, it will work, but you will also be able to see the `.env` file that was prepared by docker in your host IDE. If your intention is to hide the `.env` file from your host IDE, then this method will not work because mounting will expose that file to your host since the custom command copies the generated `.env` into the mounted folder.

Comment: So instead of volume mounting in `docker-compose` I should add `ADD ./app /var/www/app`, right?

Comment: If you use the first method, you cannot modify the files on your host IDE (since it's not meant for development). The files will be baked into the docker image, and yes, you will do `ADD ./app /var/www/app` to add those files. I was referring to the second method for the previous comments. If you want to modify files on your host IDE, you need to mount it. In the Dockerfile, copy `./app/.env.dist` to a different folder, update the contents, and define a custom docker entrypoint (a simple bash script). The bash script contains something like `cp /var/www/.env /var/www/app/.env`.

Comment: You can also use CMD in your Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd. ( i.e. `CMD ["bash" "-c" "cp /var/www/.env /var/www/app/.env && run_server_command"]` ).

Comment: @imjching And how can I pass arguments to `entryfile.sh`?

Comment: @imjching I'm trying the `CMD` solution... now the `.env` file is created as it is supposed to but... php container exits with status 0 for a change. What "run_server_command" should I use to make PHP listening?